# Excel variable in a workbook

Tags: excel, networking, automation

Thanks in advance for your help and time here.

I am trying to do a bit of network config automation using Excel and would appreciate some help.

How do I define a variable (or a value) in Excel which will be replaced in any sheets in the same workbook with the value defined for that variable?

For example, I want to define a variable "reth1.0" (whose value is say 1.1.1.1) which will replace "reth1.0" (with 1.1.1.1) in any of the sheets that variable is called out?

On Sheet1, I'll have a cell which is referenced as reth1.0, any value I put in that cell should change the variable "reth1.0" called out in Sheet2 in the same workbook

Thanks again!

Comment: Use a named range.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, say `Sheet1!A1` shows the value `1.1.1.1`.  If you create a Named Range for `Sheet1!A1`, called `reth1.0`, you can use `=reth1.0` elsewhere in the workbook to refer directly to that cell.  Then, changing the value of `A1` will update all the others.

[image]